# MVC 3 default site displaying IE Post security message

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

When I publish the default MVC 3 Razor site and attempt click the Login or Register buttons in internet explorer I get prompted with "When you send information to the internet, it might be possible for others to see that information. Do you want to continue".

I assumed this was just happening on my machine but it seems like it is happen to all my MVC 3 sites on a form post. I'm using a http post so I was wondering if this was the issue.

Has anyone else encountered this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think this has anything to do with MVC or Razor.  Check your zone and ensure that the "Submit non-encrypted form data" setting is set to Enable.

Comment: If I publish the site to my local or debug locally I get this message. If I publish to a internal server I have the same issue but if I publish to a live server this issue seems to disappear.

Comment: @Sparkle Again, I would verify your Zone and its settings if you haven't already done so.